# Transforming images from the Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am trying to get image from Blobstore by using blobKey But I am getting Exception ***"com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'images' or call 'Transform()' was not found."***

I have refer [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/) to Transform image

Included packages

```
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Image;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Transform;
```

My code is

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey("nt6Qo5yvgQu9byMAQEprqA") ;           
ImagesService imagServ = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();           
Image oldImag = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(blobKey);            
Transform tran = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(200, 300);                     
Image newImag = imagServ.applyTransform(tran,oldImag);
byte[] newImagData = newImag.getImageData();
```

I am getting Exception on 5th line of my code i.e here`Image newImag = imagServ.applyTransform(tran,oldImag);`

Answer (score 1):

How are you deploying the code? Please make sure the library is in the build path and it's deployed properly then try again. I tried the exact tutorial and it worked, I am using Eclipse though.